# Invoke Serverless lambda from another function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am trying to call a serverless lambda function from another lambda. Both lambdas live inside the same serverless project. Can I achieve this natively from within my function code, for example calling the handler function directly? Or would I need to use the AWS SDK and use lambda.invoke ? I would prefer to call the lambda function directly if possible

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a lambda client.invoke() from within your lambda?

Something along the lines of:

```
lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName=called_function,
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=bytes(json.dumps(event_to_send))
    )
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am actually trying to avoid (if possible). I was trying to figure out if I can just consume the other lambda handler function, and invoke that directly like any other function. I'm curious if this would work

Comment: Right, gotcha. I don't think you can avoid this, unfortunately. Are you trying to avoid it for testing reasons? The only other way I could see this happening (avoiding the lambda_client.invoke() call, but not having a native function call either) would be to write to an AWS DB and put a trigger on writes to then call your child lambda. But not sure if this fits your use case.

Comment: I ended up invoking the underlying function that the lambda kicks off. It's not the same as invoking the lambda directly, but I still got to the business logic I was after